# EmberJS, how to query the model with getter functions?

Tags: ember.js

I don't know if I asked correctly, but instead of having the collection of data, I would like to compute the data based on parameter. Something like:

```
var date = new Date();
var events = model.getEvents(date);

{{#each event in events}}
  event
{{/each}}
```

The difference being here that **getEvents** does both the fetching from server, plus local computation and transformation before returning the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would probably be to use the `setupController` hook on your route to fetch the list of events, then set it as the `events` property in your controller.

```
App.SomeRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController : function(controller,model){
    var date = new Date();
    var events = model.getEvents(date);
    controller.set('events',events)
  }
});
```

Comment: Well I'd like to supply the date from the view, whatever date the user selects. Then fetch, then construct the model, and return (or bind, whatever it is).